# invalid factor level, NA generated in the table

Tags: r

I am trying to find names in one column and replace with it another column.
Here is an example:

```
V1
some_information1    gene_id rna-NC_020    transcript_id rna-NC_020; gbkey tRNA; product tRNA-Phe;   
some_information2    gene_id rna-NC_7567    transcript_id rna-NC_7567; gbkey CDS; gene SP4; 
some_information3    gene_id rna-NC_59    transcript_id rna-NC_59; gbkey CDS; sprot sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN;
```

And here is what I want as result:

```
V1
some_information1    gene_id tRNA-Phe    transcript_id rna-NC_020; gbkey tRNA; product tRNA-Phe;   
some_information2    gene_id SP4    transcript_id rna-NC_7567; gbkey CDS; gene SP4; 
some_information3    gene_id sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN    transcript_id rna-NC_59; gbkey CDS; sprot sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN;
```

I tried to make it with regular expressions in loop

```
library(stringr)
for (i in 1:nrow(gtf2)){
  gene = as.character(str_extract(gtf2$V3[i], regex("gene .*?;")))
  sprot = as.character(str_extract(gtf2$V3[i], regex("sprot .*?;")))
  product = as.character(str_extract(gtf2$V3[i], regex("product .*?;")))
  if (!is.na(gene)){
    gtf2$V2[i] = paste("gene_id", as.character(unlist(strsplit(gene, " ")[[1]])[2]), collapse = " ")
  }
  else if (!is.na(sprot)){
    cat(sprot)
    gtf2$V2[i] = paste("gene_id", as.character(unlist(strsplit(sprot, " ")[[1]])[2]), collapse = " ")
    cat(gtf2$V2[i])
  }
  else if (!is.na(product)){
    gtf2$V2[i] = paste("gene_id", as.character(unlist(strsplit(product, " ")[[1]])[2]), collapse = " ")
  }
}
```

But as results I obtained NAs and warning:

`` In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = "gene_id tRNA-Ser;") : invalid factor level, NA generated ``

How can i fix it?

Comment: I resolved this problem by adding ```stringsAsFactors=FALSE``` in read.table when uploaded data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub` to extract the pattern that you are looking for.

```
sub('.*(gene|product|sprot)\\s(.*)', '\\2', gtf2$other)
#[1] "tRNA-Phe"              "SP4;"                  "sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Elya, you can simplify what you want to do. Most importantly, you do not need to loop over your data.
I assume your example data is representative for your dataset. In particular, the information in `other` is separated by a semi-colon. In this case you can split the string by it and extract from your 3rd column the part required to add to the "gene_id" fragment in your 2nd column. Based on your comment I append a solution for multiple hits in the other column.

Note: the following names these columns "info", "gene_id", and "other". Make sure to adapt the variable naming.

**data**

```
V1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~info,          ~gene_id,                           ~other,
  "some_information1", "gene_id rna-NC_020", "transcript_id rna-NC_020; gbkey tRNA; product tRNA-Phe",
  "some_information2", "gene_id rna-NC_7567", "transcript_id rna-NC_7567; gbkey CDS; gene SP4;",
  "some_information3", "gene_id rna-NC_59", "transcript_id rna-NC_59; gbkey CDS; sprot sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN"  
)
```

**Extract the fragment from 3rd column**

```
V1 %>% 
  select(other) %>% 
  mutate(fragment = str_split(string=other, pattern = ";", simplify = TRUE)[,3])
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  other                                                           fragment                      
  <chr>                                                           <chr>                         
1 transcript_id rna-NC_020; gbkey tRNA; product tRNA-Phe          " product tRNA-Phe"           
2 transcript_id rna-NC_7567; gbkey CDS; gene SP4;                 " gene SP4"                   
3 transcript_id rna-NC_59; gbkey CDS; sprot sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN " sprot sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN"
```

**Putting it all together**

For this we `paste()` the extracted fragment to "gene_id" and overwrite the previous `gene_id column`. If your full data is a bit more complex, you would have to adapt this as required.

```
V1 %>% 
  mutate(gene_id = paste0(
            ]"gene_id"
           , str_split(string=other, pattern = ";", simplify = TRUE)[,3])
   )
```

And voila:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  info              gene_id                             other                                                          
  <chr>             <chr>                               <chr>                                                          
1 some_information1 gene_id product tRNA-Phe            transcript_id rna-NC_020; gbkey tRNA; product tRNA-Phe         
2 some_information2 gene_id gene SP4                    transcript_id rna-NC_7567; gbkey CDS; gene SP4;                
3 some_information3 gene_id sprot sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN transcript_id rna-NC_59; gbkey CDS; sprot sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN
```

**Amendment based on comment**

If the string you are parsing comprises multiple hits (e.g. product, gene, and/or sprot), you could use a text-mining approach.
Note: there can be a way to solve this with regex - I cannot, others might help here.

Let's add the multi-hit string to our data:

```
V1 <- V1 %>% bind_rows(c(
  info = "some info4", gene_id = "gene_id xxx"
,other = "gene_id cds-YP_007626758.1; transcript_id cds-YP_007626758.1; Parent gene-ND1; Dbxref Genbank:YP_007626758.1,GeneID:15088436; Name YP_007626758.1; Note TAAstopcodoniscompletedbytheadditionof3'AresiduestothemRNA; gbkey CDS; gene ND1; product NADHdehydrogenasesubunit1; protein_id YP_007626758.1; transl_except (pos:3700..3700%2Caa:TERM); transl_table 2") )
```

To solve this problem we use `{tidytext}` and break the string into tokens.
The magic function here is `unnest_tokens()`.
Let's see how this works:

```
library(tidytext)
V1 %>% unnest_tokens(
    output = fragment                           # name of our output column
  , input = other                               # input column name
  , token = stringr::str_split, pattern = "; "  # how to tokenise, we use split and the semi-colon
  , to_lower = FALSE                            # overwrite default to_lower
)
```

With this we get:

```
# A tibble: 21 x 3
   info              gene_id             fragment                       
   <chr>             <chr>               <chr>                      
 1 some_information1 gene_id rna-NC_020  transcript_id rna-NC_020   
 2 some_information1 gene_id rna-NC_020  gbkey tRNA                 
 3 some_information1 gene_id rna-NC_020  product tRNA-Phe           
 4 some_information2 gene_id rna-NC_7567 transcript_id rna-NC_7567  
 5 some_information2 gene_id rna-NC_7567 gbkey CDS
```

We can now extract (filter) the desired fragments. In order to combine the fragments belonging to a specific entry we add an id-column and combine the filtered fragments.

```
V1 %>% 
# ---------------- add an entry id per row -----------------------
   mutate(entry = row_number()) %>% 
# ---------------- break into text fragments ---------------------
   unnest_tokens(output = fragment, input = other, to_lower = FALSE
                , token = stringr::str_split, pattern = "; ") %>%
# ---------------- filter desired fragments ----------------------
   filter(grepl(pattern = "^(gene|sprot|product)", fragment)) %>% 
# ----------------- per entry group combine fragments --------------
   group_by(entry) %>% 
   summarise(full_term = paste(fragment, collapse = ", "))
```

This will get you:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  entry full_term                                                              
  <int> <chr>                                                                  
1     1 product tRNA-Phe                                                       
2     2 gene SP4;                                                              
3     3 sprot sp|A6NI73|LIRA5_HUMAN                                            
4     4 gene_id cds-YP_007626758.1, gene ND1, product NADHdehydrogenasesubunit1
```

You can have this now inserted in your desired output. For example with a join or you write a function and have this called from the aforementioned pipe (make sure to remove the entry column).

Comment: thank you for your answer! I forgot one detail about data: there aren't fixed number of fields in third column. For example:
gene_id "cds-YP_007626758.1"; transcript_id "cds-YP_007626758.1"; Parent "gene-ND1"; Dbxref "Genbank:YP_007626758.1,GeneID:15088436"; Name "YP_007626758.1"; Note "TAAstopcodoniscompletedbytheadditionof3'AresiduestothemRNA"; gbkey "CDS"; gene "ND1"; product "NADHdehydrogenasesubunit1"; protein_id "YP_007626758.1"; transl_except "(pos:3700..3700%2Caa:TERM)"; transl_table "2"

Comment: Hi Elya, this added a quite interesting problem to your question. I am not a regex expert. Shoutout to @Ronak Shah providing a (partial) regex based solution. Since I could not fix it with a regex, I looked at {tidytext} package. This allows you to easily extract the string fragments which you can then filter and reassemble. Hope that gets you going.